# remove dynamic columns on button click using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, button, click, reset

I have a HTML table containing labels and textboxes with the following structure.

```
lb1 tb1 | lb2 tb2 | lb3 tb3 | lb4 tb4
```

Initially this table is hidden. On a button click, I add in a few dynamic columns to it. So after the button click, the table looks like below

```
 lb1 tb1         | lb2 tb2         | lb3 tb3  | dynalb1 dynatb1
 dynalb2 dynatb2 | dynalb3 dynatb3 | lb4 tb4
```

I do this by creating a new table and modifying its html structure dynamically and finally replacing the old table with the new one.To do this I use the jquery function

```
$('#old_table').replaceWith(mynewtable);  // old_table is static table's id
```

This above part works well.

Now I want to return to the orginal table structure(the static table), on click of a reset button. How can i do that.

I have tried the following

```
$('#Reset').click(function(){  
$('#mynewtable').replaceWith($('#old_table'));
});

$('#Reset').click(function(){  
$('#old_table').remove();
});

$('#Reset').click(function(){  
$('#old_table').detach();
});

$('#Reset').click(function(){  
$('#old_table').empty();
});

$('#Reset').click(function(){  
$('#old_table').remove();
});
```

But nothing seems to work. Can Someone please tell how to get back to the original html table.

Answer (score 0):

1) you have "table1".

2) now take another table "table2" under the "table1" and set style display:none to it.

3) now do same job to making table and replace table content but with "table2".

4) and set display:block to "table2" and set display:none to "table1".

5) and in reset button click function set display:block to "table1" and set display:none to "table2".

> it simple, i hope it is useful for u.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class to the labels and textboxes and replace your jQuery with this:

```
$('#Reset').click(function(){  
    $('yourDivOrWhatever').removeClass('newClass');
});
```